# How to move the focus to required field in xml during onchange event odoo?

Tags: xml, focus, odoo-8

I want move the **focus** of the field to desired field during a on change event.
Is it possible in **odoo8** without altering the core code?.

[Image - Field Focus](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z6AAc.png)

Comment: you want to do this on which condition? always, always in that view or that would depend on the result of the onchange python code? in the two first case I think it would be possible by a custom module adding javascript.

Comment: I want to move the focus from field 1 to field 8, if on change event on field 1 is triggered. Focus need to be moved should be depended on python onchnage function.

Comment: Did you found a solution to this problem?